# Best approach to turn a physical soda can into a 3D file?

Tags: 3d, scanning

For clarification: I don't need it to turn into a 3D design in the end. I just need to be able to print an exact replica of a can with as much detail as possible.

So, I'm a huge fan of Monster Energy drinks. In particular their Mango Loco variant. I want to do some cool designs using their colors and designs (for my own personal use), but I haven't been able to find the design they use for their cans online.

I was thinking about opening up a can carefully, slicing it down on one side, and then placing it in a regular paper scanner. I was also thinking about simply scanning the can, turn it 10-20 degrees, scan it again, and repeat that until I've turned it 360 degrees around, and then stitch all the parts together.

Walmart has some high resolution and highly detailed images of these cans taken from the side, but I can't stitch them together without creating a warped image, because there are only 4 images (of the same angle). You can find them here:  https://www.walmart.com/ip/Monster-Mango-Loco-Energy-Juice-16-Fl-Oz/738711334

I don't have a fancy rig or a great camera (best one is in my Galaxy Note 10+), so I'd have to build one, except I would also need a lot of lighting and so on.

This is the kind of design I am looking for in the end, but you can probably see what I mean by saying it's warped: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3wo.jpg

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Apart from hiring a product photographer to take some photos, the best way would be to begin with the original artwork, and then wrap that around the a can in 3D modelling software. Assuming you have permission to do this, then simply contact the manufacturer for the original artwork. If you don't have permission, then that's a whole other can of copyright-infringement worms, and I can't (and won't) help you there. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi and thanks @BillyKerr! Unfortunately I do not have the artwork, but I have contacted the manufacturer to see if that's possible to get. I've placed the can in my scanner, but because the light from the scanner is only in one spot, you can clearly see the reflections on the aluminum :( I'll wait for the manufacturer. Thanks!